# ng2: Events fired when routerOutlet has loaded the component

Tags: angular

I'm having a "*router-outlet*" on my page and I need to be able to access the "*loadedComponent*" properties as soon as it is available. Currently, I have another component on my view (besides the "*router-outlet*") that fires an event when it is loaded. I try to access the component loaded by the "*router-outlet*" at that moment but it is "*null*" and the property "*isLoaded*" is "*false*".

I guess it's because the component is not yet loaded in the "*router-outlet*" one but I don't really want to do a "*setInterval*" as long as the component is not loaded. I checked the documentation of the "*router-outlet*" component but it does not look like there is an event like this.

Does someone have an idea about this?

Comment: You can create a custom implementation of `<router-outlet>` that does what you want. See http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/ for an example.

Comment: I'm gonna read this. So far, I fixed my issue by subscribing to "router.changes" ("router" being the "Router" service), but you article seems to be worth reading. Thanks